# How can one Docker Container find the IP address of another Docker Container?

Tags: docker, microservices

Working on my first MSA application, and trying to figure out how a Docker container can find the IP address of another Docker Container?  My containers know the name of the other container it needs to connect to, but that is it.  I can't use a "--link" option or docker-compose as the components can come an go at different times, and I need a programmatic way to find the IP address of the other containers and start connections to them.

I have to think this problem has already been solved long long ago, but my GoogleFoo must be very weak today, as I can't find anything!

Thanks for your help! :)

AAR:
So the issue is that on the default 'bridge' bridge network, the Docker DNS does NOT keep track of container names...all other network types it will.

So the accepted solution below is to use any other network and have the containers use that network.

I created another bridge network so that I can still do testing/dev work, and my containers can find one another by name now. For production, I will have to change the network to something like a 'macvlan' type.

If you are using something like Kubernetes, then you will need a Service Discovery solution like Zookeeper or Consul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define network in your docker-compose as below

```
networks:
  my-network:
```

And then make both the containers part of the same network.

```
networks:
  - my-network
```

And they can access other docker service port using docker service name.

EDIT 2:
Without dokcer-compose I am able to communicate 2 containers as below:

1) Created netwrok - my-netwrok

```
docker network create -d bridge my-network
```

2) Started 2 service unders same network

```
docker run -d --name eureka --network=my-network eureka-service:1.0
docker run -d --name facility --network=my-network facility-service:1.0
```

3) Logged in to facility container

```
docker exec -it facility bash
```

4) pinged eureka from inside facility container

```
bash-4.4# ping eureka
PING eureka (172.18.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.149 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.078 ms
```

Comment: AGAIN: no use of docker-compose.  What is the "docker service name" and how does a Docker container use it to query the IP address of the other Docker container??????  I'm not asking how to do networking on Docker....I just need to get the IP address of another Docker container where I only have the container name to query with.

Comment: Why you need to know IP address if you can communicate using docker service name. Docker service name is nothing but the root tag when you start defining a docker.

Comment: The same concept you can use without docker-compose. You just need to define the netwrok using docker network create -d bridge my-network and make the container part of the same netwrok when running continer by providing --netwrok=my-netwrok

Comment: " communicate using docker service name" ...ok, great, how is that done?  client.connect("msgbus") returns UNKOWNADDRESS error.  "msgbus' is the name of the other Docker container, but just using the name of the container does not resolve via DNS

Comment: msgbug container also part of the same network? The same works for me.

Comment: Yes, they are all using the default bridge network.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215211/discussion-between-alok-singh-and-jd-allen).